# Which limitations v-model has in Vue 2.x?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Maybe below problems of `v-model` has solutions, but I have not see the appropriate documentation.

- "Chaining" the v-model: e. g. we want custom component has the `v-model`, and this `v-model` is related with child `<input>`'s element's `v-model`.
- Using the objects (including arrays which is the particular case of ECMAScript's `object`) as `v-model`.
- Modifying data: e. g. users inputs only digits, but the value which component emits is comma separated number (for the instance, iser's input: "4545667", emitted value: "4,545,667")

The first question in my research: what v-model can not do?

Answer (score 2):

[`v-model="formData"` === `v-bind:value="formData" v-on:input="formData = $event.target.value"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). It's not a magic command that does everything, but a shorter way to write a basic functionality.

To get the behaviour you need, you have to write your own components that take the value and do something with it.

To chain v-model between multiple layers of components, you want to `$emit` the new data rather than the default behaviour of changing the components' state. The easiest way to do this is by using [a computed getter/setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). I use the code below to pass through anything from simple values to entire objects to custom input components that handle the binding to different html inputs.

```
--- ParentTemplate:
<Child v-model="formData"></Child>

-- ChildTemplate:
<input v-model="localValue">

-- ChildScript:
computed: {
    localValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(localValue) {
        this.$emit('input', localValue);
      },
    },
  },
```

If you need to convert data from an input before it's sent out (eg formatting), you can use a computed value or method to transform the data before you $emit it in the setter.